# Repetitive calculating distance between two values Excel

Tags: excel, count, binary, formula

In a single binary column, made up only from 0 and 1 (011111011110101111011), I want to calculate the distance between zeros (as shown in the following image), or to count the amount of consecutive 1 in the column and restart the counting as soon as a 0 comes up in the list.

[image]

Can someone please give any idea which formulas to combine?

I can get it to calculate the first group, but as soon as the second 0 shows up, I don't know how to restart counting from that point.

Comment: formula cannot merge cells.  Are those already existing? Or are they just there to show the grouping?  If not necessary would you please [edit] the post to include how you want the output from the formula without the merged cells?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can test this, but it gives the count in the cell next to the zero...

[image]

```
=IF(A2=1,"",ROW()-COUNTIF(A$1:A2,0)-SUM(B$1:B1))
```

So, it might just be a start for you to edit as you need.

Comment: `ROW()-COUNTIF(A$1:A2,0)-SUM(B$1:B1)` can probably be shortened to `SUM(A$1:A2)-SUM(B$1:B1)` as they are all 1's and 0's.  Also if you change the COUNTIF to count the `1`:  `COUNTIF(A$1:A2,1)-SUM(B$1:B1)` you can remove the reference to it own row.  That way if the OP has title row(s) or other things above, we get a proper count.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to do something like this, I use two additional columns.

In the column next to the data (i.e. B) enter 1 in the top cell (B1).

In the rest of the cells in column B enter the formula (here for cell B2):

```
=IF(A2=A1;B1+1;1)
```

This will add 1 to the previous number if there is a 1 in column A, and otherwise reset the count to 1, so it keeps track of a running total of the number of consecutive 1's (or zeroes for that matter).

Now in Column C, add the following formula in all the cells (hier formulated for cell C1):

```
=IF(AND((A1=1);(A2<>1));B1;"")
```

This simply checks if it is the last 1 in the series and copies the value from column B, or else returns an empty string. The result looks like this:

The [image: Resulting appearance with formulas]

Then you can hide column B to only show the result in column C.