# Excel - How to count streaks of non-zero numbers on one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a wordcount column with various numbers but each cell has a formula. So I'd like to count only the cells that have a non-zero number and stop when it hits a zero. A streak in other words.

```
Daily session count
100
200
400
100
200
=IF(C9<>"",SUM(C9-C8),"")
200
300
=IF(C9<>"",SUM(C9-C8),"")
=IF(C9<>"",SUM(C9-C8),"")
=IF(C9<>"",SUM(C9-C8),"")
=IF(C9<>"",SUM(C9-C8),"")
```

the longest streak in this example would be 5. What formula could I use for this? I use this for Google Sheets but I need it to work for EXCEL.

```
=INDEX(COLUMNS(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY('Daily Count'!B2:B,,9^9)), " 0 ", )), " ")))
```

Edit: So the cells with 0 actually have a formula in them (meaning they are not empty) however they are only populated when the adjacent cell is updated with a daily wordcount, and so the daily session count is updated.

If I've missed a day of writing I still add the daily word count which means the daily session count is "0". Again, what I'm looking for is to count the cells in a column, as the longest streak of integers above 0. Thanks :)

Comment: Basically the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70340291/repetitive-calculating-distance-between-two-values-excel/70422775#70422775

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With ms365, try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=MAX(SCAN(0,A1:A9,LAMBDA(a,b,(a+(b<>0))*(b<>0))))
```

Or, with `LET()` nested:

```
=MAX(SCAN(0,A1:A9,LAMBDA(a,b,LET(x,b<>0,(a+x)*x))))
```

Comment: So this works, but I have formulas in the cells, so it is counting those. I need it to only count cells that have a number value in them.

Comment: @Kinglouie, can you update you question with a better sample data set.

Comment: Hey @JvdV any chance you could update your answer? Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

`=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A9,ROW(A1:A9)),IF(A1:A9=0,ROW(A1:A9))))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in excel:

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A9<>0,ROW(A1:A9)),IF(A1:A9=0,ROW(A1:A9))))
```

This is an array formula, so please hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter

A1:A9 is assumed your range.