# How can I merge these two formulas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-lambda

I'm trying to merge these two formulas so that it only works out the streak if the cell has a number (each cell has a formula in it but is blank)

**Formula 1**

```
=MAX(SCAN(0,B1:B,LAMBDA(a,b,(a+(b<>0))*(b<>0))))
```

**Formula 2**

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B1:B).....Do a thing.....)
```

Some Test Data:

```
Daily session count
100
200
400
100
200
=IF(C9<>"",SUM(C9-C8),"")
200
300
=IF(C9<>"",SUM(C9-C8),"")
=IF(C9<>"",SUM(C9-C8),"")
=IF(C9<>"",SUM(C9-C8),"")
=IF(C9<>"",SUM(C9-C8),"")
```

The issue is related to this question:
[Excel - How to count streaks of non-zero numbers on one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71349750/excel-how-to-count-streaks-of-non-zero-numbers-on-one-column)

Comment: `B1:B` is not a valid excel reference.

Comment: Also can you mock up some test data and expected output?

Comment: So I just need Formula 1 to only function if the cell is a number

Comment: yes but you are trying to combine a test on an array with a formula that outputs a single result.  So it does not make a lot of sense.  a picture of the data and expected output would help us help you.

Comment: Sure thing, added some more detail. Thanks

Comment: just change the `0` to `""`: `=MAX(SCAN(0,B1:B,LAMBDA(a,b,(a+(b<>""))*(b<>""))))`

Comment: And if you want to do both `""` and `0` then: `=MAX(SCAN(0,B1:B10,LAMBDA(a,b,(a+((b<>"")*(b<>0)))*(b<>"")*(b<>0))))`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Scott Craner for the answer here. The final solution was this:

`=MAX(SCAN(0,B1:B1000,LAMBDA(a,b,(a+(b<>""))*(b<>0))))`

This allowed me to measure the longest streak of numbers in a column full of blank cells (with formulas)